# terminal can't use shadowsocks and git after upgrade to 18.04 from 16.04

Tags: networking, 18.04

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a physical machine and upgrade to 18.04 recently. After upgrade, my terminal can't use **shadowsocks** anymore and **git** related operations show timeout. But i can still access **google.com** through browser. I checked that both the **shadowsocks** and **privoxy** services are working.The firewall was also turned off by `ufw disable` command. Any help would be greatful.